# How can I force iOS to change background color immediately?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, animation

Is there any way to change the background color of a window immediately?

I need a blinking background, i.e. red/green blinking in an interval of a second. As i see, the background color will not change immediately, but only when function is left.

Is there any way to force the system to change it and redraw the window's background immediately?

Comment: If you feel answer is correct, accept it. So that others can refer it easily. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Naveen has given a good first start, but you can show a little more class by animating the colour change.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set up the initial background colour
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    // Set up a repeating timer.
    // This is a property,
    self.changeBgColourTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(changeColour) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void) changeColour {
    // Don't just change the colour - give it a little animation. 
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        // No need to set a flag, just test the current colour.
        if ([self.view.backgroundColor isEqual:[UIColor redColor]]) {
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        } else {
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        } 
    }];

    // Now we're done with the timer.
    [self.changeBgColourTimer invalidate];
    self.changeBgColourTimer = nil;
}
```

Comment: how/where do you define changeBgColourTimer?

Comment: 9th line of the code snippet which begins `self.changeBgColourTimer = …`

Comment: I got this error: Property 'changeBgColourTimer' not found on object of type 'Viewcontroller', sorry i am totally newbie, just trying out the codes

Comment: in your viewcontroller header (.h) add the line `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *changeBgColourTimer;`

Comment: In this case I'd put it in a class extension in the implementation file. It's not a property that needs to be in the public interface.

Comment: i tried to change the color every 1 second so i made it 0.1 but the green color just stays and does not change to anything else ...

Answer (score 6):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    flag = YES;
    NSTimer *mTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5
                                                       target:self 
                                                     selector:@selector(changeColor)
                                                     userInfo:nil
                                                      repeats:YES];  
}

- (void)changeColor
{
    if (flag == YES)
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        flag = NO;
        return;
    }
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    flag = YES;

}
```